# Backing up an old version of WP before upgrading

Tags: backup

I just took over a site running 3.3.1 and I'd like to back up the site and move it to local host so I can test the upgrade process locally to make sure nothing breaks. I've looked at BackWPup but it requires WP 3.4 to do it's thing. I also looked at BackUpWordPress but it needs 3.3.3. Anybody know a tool that will back up a site that's running 3.3.1 or will I need to manually it up?

Comment: And the manual backup can be this way: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/110460/22728

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for plugin-like solution I know great one for backing up straight to dropbox to keep your data safe [WordPress Backup to Dropbox](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-backup-to-dropbox/)

It looks like it should fit your version, even if it doesn't backing up manually isin't hard at all. If you want to back up manually theres is basically 3 easy steps:

- Download all the files from ftp server, put them to your local host
  directory where you want to keep them.

  - Login to phpmyadmin panel and export .sql file of your wordpress installation.
  - Import downloaded database into your local host phpmyadmin or any way you want, go to wp_options table and change siteurl and home fields of old site to something like `http://localhost/backedupsite`
  - Edit wp-config.php whitch is located in root folder of your wp, change lines 19 to your database name, line 22 to your localhost user (usualy root) and line 25  with your password (usualy empty or root)

That's all if there's still something unclear, let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

What you will need to do in order to avoid breaking links is to change the server path and site url which clearly will be different for a local installation.

The easiest way to do this is to use a [plugin like WP Migrate DB](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) where you simply enter in the 2 new settings before exporting the database.

1. Then you can download the WordPress files (old version) and overwrite your local WordPress files with the old version
2. Create a new database
3. Change the wp-config.php connection details to your new database details
4. Import your database into your local installation using phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a plugin to backup, though they are convenient. You will have to find an older version that will run under 3.3.1.

Best thing to do is see the docs at http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Backups and do a manual backup. You can backup the database with phpmyadmin or adminer, and you can download the theme to your PC to make a copy.

After backing up, manually upgrade Wordpress to 3.5, and then you can auto update to 3.8.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation and I did not have time to do the manual backup.

I found a list of older BackWPup plugins here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/backwpup/developers/

And I installed version 2.1.9. It backed up the site to a new folder I created in the /public_html/ folder. Then I upgraded from 3.3.1 to 4.2.2 without incident. After that, I updated the BackWPup plugin to the suitable version for the new WP upgrade.

I did notice that after doing the first job, the screen said 100% done but never went to a verification page. I went into my file manager to make sure that the zip file was in the new archive folder. It was there and when I checked the log, the download was complete. That's a small thing tho, as long as it said 100% and you checked your back up location.